# Astropy get table length

Tags: python-3.x, astropy

How can I get the length (i.e. number of rows) of an astropy Table? From [the documentation](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/), there are serveral ways of having the table length printed out, such as `t.info()`. However, I can't use this information in a script.

How do I assign the length of a table to a variable?

Comment: `len(t)` should work.

Comment: @GeoMSI How did I not think of that? Yes, it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python the `len()` built-in function typically gives the length/size of some collection-like object.  For example the length of a 1-D array is given like:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> len(a)
3
```

For a table you could ask what the "size" of a table means--the number of rows?  The number of columns?  The total number of items in the table?  But it sounds like you want the number of *rows*.  In Python, this will almost always be given by `len()` on table-like objects as well (arguably anything that does otherwise is a mistake).  You can consider this by analogy to how you might construct a table-like data structure with simple Python lists, by nesting them:

```
>>> t = [
...         [1, 2, 3],
...         [4, 5, 6],
...         [7, 8, 9]
...     ]
```

Here each "row" is represented by a single list nested in outer lists, so `len(t)` gives th number of rows.  In fact this is just a convention and *can* be broken if need-be.  For example you could also treat the above `t` as list of columns for some column-oriented data.

But in Python we typically assume 2-dimensional arrays to be row-oriented unless otherwise stated--to remember you can see that the syntax for a nested list as I wrote above *looks* row-oriented.

The logic extends to Numpy arrays and other more complicated data structures built on them such as Astropy's `Table` or Pandas `DataFrame`s.